# Can I show a relation - "Either in this table or in that " in ER diagram?

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

I am making a database for handling leave applications in an academic institute. Given that there is hierarchy existent in such institutes, and I need to keep record of the people that were at these posts, say 'Dean', I have implemented a table 'archived_cross_cutting_faculty' in addition to 'current_cross_cutting_faculty', where cross_cutting_faculty means the guy is dean or something else in addition to being a faculty.
To have a record of retired faculty, i have table retired_faculty in addition to faculty table.

Now, the faculty listed in archived_cross_cutting maybe a retired faculty, hence he maybe in the retired_faculty table. Or he maybe present in the faculty table, i.e. he is currently serving as a faculty but say, he is not a dean now.

Can this relation be shown in ER Diagram? That a person in archived_cross_cutting_faculty is either in the faculty table or in the retired_faculty table? How?

Comment: This difficulty is trying to tell you something.  You really want a single Faculty table.  When a professor retires, they don't just dissapear from the database.  Why not add StartDate and EndDate to both tables, then you can have a single `Faculty` table and a single `FacultyPosition` table?  Then you can record facts of the form: "Dr. Po, now retired, was the Dean of the school from 2014 through 2022".

Comment: I made separate table just because I thought there will be a lot values in EndDate column, and that is something that I need to avoid. However, now I can see there are problems in both the designs. But as I am new to this, I'm not able to realize which one is a bigger issue.

Comment: Always optimize your data models for simplicity.

Comment: We get a lot of similar questions here about schema design. The problem is that it is an [`iterative process`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+iterative+process)! It is basically impossible for us to tell whether a schema is appropriate for a particular scenario without knowing way more than would fit in a post here. Whatever programming language you are using, fire up your first pass at the schema, programme against it, then correct the bugs (there **will** be bugs), then rinse and repeat. If you have more specific questions, get back to us. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vérace   , David Browne, things are indeed quite open-ended in db design i guess!

Comment: `I am making a database for handling leave applications in an academic institute.`. I'm sure that you're not the first person ever to have had this (or analogous) requirement. Check this [out](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/employees_leave_record_keeping/index.htm). I searched for "open source holiday tracker academia" and there were a couple of potentially interesting [links](https://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+holiday+tracker+academia&oq=open+source+holiday+tracker+academia&aqs=chrome..69i57.10391j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Vary search terms - might get more sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ER model,  this concept is known as Generalization/Specialization.  A diagram illustrating this is shown in the artcle linked to.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generalization-specialization-and-aggregation-in-er-model/

A word of caution is in order, however.  Gen/spec is applied to Entities, not tables. The difference between entities and tables is in the level of abstraction.  If you want to think clearly about the subject matter,  and not just the database, it behooves you to keep the levels distinct in your mind.
An entity is an object in the subject matter whose descriptive data may be stored in a table.